# Generalized API declaration for multiple models

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, crud

In the process of developing a JWT application with Django I noticed the declaration pattern of the CRUD API View, such as:

```py
class Create(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = <some django model>.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializer # <some serializer class>


class Read(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = <some django model>.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializer # <some serializer class>


class Update(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = <some django model>.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializer # <some serializer class>


class Delete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = <some django model>.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializer # <some serializer class>
```

Considering that my specific project has 7 models that have to have these functionalities, instead of declaring 28 versions of the above classes, I think it would be more elegant if there were a class such as:

```py
class Create(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def __init__(self, model, serializer):
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()
        self.serializer_class = serializer
        super().__init__()


class Read(generics.ListAPIView):
    def __init__(self, model, serializer):
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()
        self.serializer_class = serializer
        super().__init__()


class Update(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def __init__(self, model, serializer):
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()
        self.serializer_class = serializer
        super().__init__()


class Delete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    def __init__(self, model, serializer):
        self.queryset = model.objects.all()
        self.serializer_class = serializer
        super().__init__()

class CRUD:
    """Base class for CRUD Operations"""

    def __init__(self, model, serializer):
        self.create = Create(model, serializer)
        self.read = Read(model, serializer)
        self.update = Update(model, serializer)
        self.delete = Delete(model, serializer)
```

That is followed by those instaciations:

```py
Reg_API = CRUD(Registry, RegistrySerializer)
Tag_API = CRUD(Tag, TagSerializer)
# etc
```

If I test on `python manage.py shell`, the instance `Reg_API.create.queryset` returns exactly what I need. But if I run `python manage.py runserver` and try to access the route, I get `__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'model' and 'serializer'`...

On urls.py my routes are defined as:

```py
from .crud import Reg_API

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/registry/create', Reg_API.create.as_view())
]
```

So I wonder what is missing here. There is something I am forgetting, or there is some reason I should follow the 28 declarations way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redesign a functionality that is already there. What you want to achieve is already there in DRF and called a [viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). For your case, this code is enough for the entire Registry CRUD API:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class RegistryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Registry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrySerializer
```

Then in your urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import RegistryViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'registry', RegistryViewSet, basename='registry')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```